# how get month and year of date now like August2020 using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to add images in folder `public\storage\annonces\August2020` and link `annonces\August2020\annonces.jpg` in database but it create a folder name `82020` in racing `public\storage\annonces\82020`,but for me i want create a folder name Monthnow2020 like `August2020`

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $Annonce = new Annonce($request->all());
       $jdate = Carbon::now();
       if($request->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $image->storeAs("public\annonces\ ".$jdate->month.$jdate->year,'annonces'.".".$image->extension());
        $Annonce->image = "annonces\ ".$jdate->month.$jdate->year."annonces" .".".$image->extension(); 
        }
        $Annonce->save();
        return Redirect::to("annonces")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

Comment: use Carbon
$jdate->format('F'); will give you monthname

Answer (score 0):

just put `\` to create new folder and use date `now()->format('F').now()->format('Y')` function

```php
 $dateFromat = now()->format('F').now()->format('Y');
 $image->storeAs("public\annonces\ ".$dateFromat.'\annonces'.".".$image->extension());
 $Annonce->image = "annonces\ ".$dateFromat."\annonces" .".".$image->extension();
```

like above

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon's `englishMonth` function to get the month name.

```php
$image->storeAs("public\annonces\ ".$jdate->englishMonth() . $jdate->year,'annonces'.".".$image->extension());
$Annonce->image = "annonces\ ".$jdate->englishMonth().$jdate->year."annonces" .".".$image->extension();
```

Source: Carbon [documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters)

Answer (score 0):

A much better refactoring could be done in a cleaner way and achieve the goal you want in this way.

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $Annonce = new Annonce($request->all());

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
            "annonces" . \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('F\Y'), 'annonces'
        );
        $Annonce->image = $path;
    }
    
    $Annonce->save();

    return Redirect::to('annonces')
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
}
```